# Parameter optimization for NEAT-Python

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm, neat

I've been using the NEAT-Python module (found here https://github.com/CodeReclaimers/neat-python) and have been able to get it working nicely for some problems. However when transitioning to a new problem I'm finding it hard to pinpoint a good set of parameters and am reduced to pretty frantic trial & error. Does anyone know of a more reliable method for finding good parameters, or even just some intuition relating to the specifics of a problem?